# Javascript Return Value in graphql

Tags: javascript, graphql

I have an apollo-server setup in my backed, I want to use a post request API inside one of my resolvers and then use the response from that API to return it to my client. but the problem am having is the return statement is running before the API response get returned. there is my code sample bellow.

```
module.exports = {
    Mutation: {
        checkFace: async () => {
            console.log("Checking.....");

            let confidence;

            var parameters = {
              image_url1: "link to image 1",

              image_url2: "link to image 2",
            };

            facepp.post("/compare", parameters, function (err, res) {
                if (!err) {
                    confidence = res.confidence;
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });

            return confidence
        },
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `faceapp.post` is probably running asynchronously. Your `checkFace` function is correctly used as `async` that's fine, but inside where you call the POST you should await the response and then return it

```
confidence = await res.confidence;
```

Also when using the function make sure you await for it to finish, so call it with

```
let someResponse = await Mutation.checkFace();
console.log(someResponse);
```

or

```
Mutation.checkFace().then(response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Whichever you prefer depending on your situation.

https://nodejs.dev/learn/modern-asynchronous-javascript-with-async-and-await

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but the problem is I cant call the mutation function with await because its being called in the graphql schema, and If I decided to remove the return statement outside the faceapp POST request, then I cant get the return value sent to the client.

Comment: `facepp` is some freely available library or something custom?

Comment: Its its a node package for face++

Comment: @Johndev247 couldn't find documentation for it.. I'd start there and check how `facepp.post` should work and how it should be called in order to return data. I presume it's asynchronous and that's why you need to await the data.